# Drawer not responiding after "launching" fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

I've been working on an app which contains a WebView. I wasn't able to make the WebView-content fit the device screen on it's own (website doesn't support mobile phones) so I use ***DisplayMetrics*** to get the screen dimensions of the device and the scale the website manualy with an if-clause depending on the screen size.

Everything worked properly until I decided to use an drawer for navigation and thus, use fragments.

**My Problem is**, by opening the "FirstFragment" which should contain the Webview (LayoutEmulator show the Webview) and the drawer can't be used anymore from this point on. The drawer shows up but there is no possiblity to click on it to open up other fragments, also the hamburger icon in the toolbar disapperas after opening "FirstFragment".

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package user.app;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

{unnecessary code}

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                 .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new SecondFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new ThirdFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

FirstFragment.java: (The Url contains a variable)

```
package user.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import java.util.Calendar;

    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


        View myView;

        @Nullable
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);


            {from here to the end old code that worked properly in a public class}
            //get calendar week
            int kw = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - 1;

            //get screen meassures
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int width = dm.widthPixels;
            int height = dm.heightPixels;
            int dens = dm.densityDpi;
            double wi = (double) width / (double) dens;
            double hi = (double) height / (double) dens;
            double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
            double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
            double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

                {if-clause that sets scale depending on screen size,
             int scale}

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) myView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.website" + kw + "/w/example.htm");
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);

            //WebView set scale
            myWebView.setInitialScale(scale);

            return myView;

        }
    }
```

Comment: The first step is to find the shortest possible code that reproduces your problem. Read this article for how to do that [mcve]

Comment: Thanks, I trired to edit my question as shown in this article :)

Comment: Why are you returning the view right after you inflate it? You should put your return in the end of onCreateView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current example, try replacing the code

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

with

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) myView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: Thanks, findViewById now works, but then the error  appears "java.lang.NullPointerException" :/

Comment: Oh, sorry, can't read... Now the app works without crashing, but when I go to the "FirstFragment" in the emulator via the navigationdrawer I can't see the WebView element and the drawer doesn't work anymore from this point on

Comment: try removing your ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);``` line in your onCreateView method. setContentView is usually used only in an activity, not a fragment.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it, everything is working now, thanks to everyone that helped my finding a solution! :)